# Incomplete download using requests.get() - Windows vs. Linux

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a large file (> 10G) that I am trying to download using Requests.  On Windows, if I use code similar to the chopped down version below:

```
import requests


request = requests.get(MyURL, stream=True)
with open(MyFile, 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in request.iter_content(request_chunksize):
        if chunk:
            fd.write(chunk)
```

The download will be discontinued at some random point in the process, say 40% in to it.  It won't throw an exception or error out in any way, it just stops and my program will continue as if it completed.  If I modify the request to look like:

```
request = requests.get(MyURL, stream=True, timeout=(12, 6000))
```

Then on Windows the download will run to 100%.  If I move this new version of the code to Linux, I see the same results as before, where the download will stop at some random point.  Any ideas as to why this behavior may be occurring and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: most likely timing out

Comment: I agree but I am not sure why.  I can download the file manually through a browser without it ever timing out.  Furthermore, the timeout is still happening on Windows (I just realized) so this post is misleading.  I thought I had it fixed there.  Thanks.

Comment: Try setting `stream=True` as a keyword parameter to `requests.get()`. It's probably not emptying the buffer and flushing the data to file. You could then try `fd.flush()` and `os.fsync()` to force the file write and free RAM